# daq with error make: *** [Makefile:344: Makefile.in] Error 1

Tags: snort

I learn about Snort and when I install it, I must install daq. When I implement`./configure && make && sudo make install`   I see this warning:

cd . && /bin/bash /home/snort/snort_src/daq-2.0.7/missing automake-1.15 --foreign
/home/snort/snort_src/daq-2.0.7/missing: line 81: automake-1.15: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.15' is missing on your system.
You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
http://www.gnu.org/software/automake
It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf
http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/
http://www.perl.org/
make: *** [Makefile:344: Makefile.in] Error 1

I installed autoconf, automake 1.16.1,  imlement `autoreconf -f -i` before but not succeed.
Someone can help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since your installing daq-2.0.7, I assume you are installing snort version ~2.9.And which version of linux/unix OS your testing installation with?

If your on Centos7.7, here a list of neccessary packages

```
yum update -y
yum install epel-release -y
yum install gcc  gcc-c++ libnetfilter_queue libnetfilter_queue-devel git flex bison zlib zlib-devel pcre pcre-devel libdnet libdnet-devel tcpdump libnghttp2 wget xz-devel lzma -y
```

See snort documents for more details: https://www.snort.org/documents